# Arch Linux update some specific repository

Tags: linux, arch-linux, repository

How to update a specific repository database? When I use `pacman -Sy` it updates all the repositories i.e. `core`, `extra`, `community`.

Is there any option so that I can sync database for some specific repository? I know it can be done by commenting out other repositories in `pacman.conf`. If there is some specific `pacman` flag, than temporarily changing the `pacman.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from the `pacman` [man page](https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html#_upgrade_options_apply_to_em_s_em_and_em_u_em_a_id_uo_a), it does not seem to be possible no. The best you can do is edit `pacman.conf` then upate and then revert `packman,conf` to what you had before.

This is not really such a good idea though, you should always have everything updated properly.